# Authenticating to any Apache Spark web UI with LDAP

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, ldap

I am looking for a way to introduce LDAP authentication to my Apache Spark Web UIs. This includes both the main Spark Web UI and the Spark history server. The Spark instances are running inside a Kubernetes cluster and are launched both via the Spark Operator and in Standalone mode.

In the official documentation, [it says the following](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#authentication-and-authorization):

"Enabling authentication for the Web UIs is done using [javax servlet filters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). You will need a filter that implements the authentication method you want to deploy. Spark does not provide any built-in authentication filters."

When searching online, I cannot find any such filters which will enable authentication through LDAP.

My questions are:

1. Are there any such filters implemented that is open source and freely available?
2. Is there another solution to my problem which will enable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a Java Servlet filter. I didn't find a public available ldap filter, however here is a PAM Filter, we can use https://github.com/marccarre/pam-servlet-filter.
   Now, we can configure PAM to use SSSD which uses LDAP.

Hint: Use thin client and use libpam4j-1.11.jar (not the official referenced version (1.9) since i could not get it work with 1.9) and jna-4.3.0.jar. This was a working setup for me.
Add all of these 3 jars to SPARK_DIR/jars/

2. On all spark nodes execute

```
yum install sssd authconfig -y
authconfig --update --enablesssd --enablesssdauth
```

3. Add / Edit /etc/sssd/sssd.conf.
   Google how to configure this file.
   Basically you can configure here variables like ldap_uri, ldap_search_base and ldap_access_filter
4. Add following Variables in spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.ui.filters                    com.carmatechnologies.servlet.PamAuthFilter
spark.com.carmatechnologies.servlet.PamAuthFilter.param.realm spark
spark.com.carmatechnologies.servlet.PamAuthFilter.param.service system-auth
```

5. Start sssd

```
sssd -i -d 3
```

6. Start Spark UIs

Authentication should work now.

Comment: I'm using an ubuntu-based base image so "authconfig" was not available. Will this solution not work in this case?

Comment: It will still work. Authconfig is just a helper tool on rhel to adapt /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/pam.d/ files. Google 'configure pam on Ubuntu'. The alternative to all the things described above is to write your own ldap javax servlet filter. Shouldn't be complicated if you have java background.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you configured sssd.conf?